# Node not found after being initialized

Tags: rosnode, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run this code below with a python interpreter. Then I type `rosnode list` from terminal. But I cannot see the node "hello". I only see "/rosout". Why?

```
import rospy
rospy.init_node("hello")
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291243/node-not-found-after-being-initialized/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2018-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-05-15**:
What *do* you see?

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2018-05-16**:
I only see "/rosout" in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out.

The node is  created. Then it disappears because the node program terminates. I should have put `rospy.spin()` at the end of the program.

---

Originally posted by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) with karma: 186 on 2018-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0